# Deleting the last tag in alfresco

Tags: tags, alfresco

I have a weird problem:

I cannot delete the last tag from document library in Alfresco.

Example:

Document library has 3 items, A, B, C.

A has tags T1 and T2.
B has tags T2 and T3.
C has only T3.

Sidebar tags list: T1, T2, T3

I delete T3, new state is:

A has T1 and T2
B has T2
C no tags

Sidebar tags list: T1, T2

I delete T2, then:

A has T1
B has no tags
C has no tags

Sidebar tags list: T1

Now comes the weird part - i delete T1, now:

A nas no tags 
B has no tags
C has no tags

Sidebar tags list: T1

So, sidebar still has T1. (?!) I try to delete it again, i get a response saying that that tag no longer exists.

I have tried to:

1. Restart alfresco
2. delete webapps/alfresco, webapps/share, work/Catalina/alfresco and work/Catalina/share folders
3. rebuild solr index with index.recovery.mode=FULL
4. rebuild solr index manually, by deleting all the folders
5. Removed the cm:taggable aspect from all the content models and doing 1, 2, 3 and 4 again

The tag just stays in the sidebar, staring at me, grinning viciously and mocking my inability to remove it.

No matter how trivial, this is a serious issue for me. Any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? (There certainly have been the odd tag bug in the past which have been fixed)

Comment: Using 4.0.1 enterprise edition, so almost the last version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should upgrade - it looks like a bug that has been fixed since the version you're on.

I've just tried the exact steps you described, on v4.1 (latest svn checkout build). When I deleted T1 and refreshed the document library, then T1 went from the sidebar tags list, and document A no longer had it listed. It also no longer showed up in the tag manager, all as you'd expect.

I'd suggest you try with 4.0.2, and hopefully it'll be fixed in that. If not, have a chat with support (you've got an Enterprise subscription so they're there to help!), and they'll hopefully be able track down exactly when it was fixed and help you get a version with the fix in it.

Comment: The only problem is that since i have a bunch of custom modules && plugins && functionality, I have to do it taking baby steps and see if something broke.

Comment: Support might be able to advise you on the files changed in the fix, which might allow for you to do your own custom backport, but I would generally suggest upgrading for all the other bug fixes!

Comment: To see what was fixed and when, check out the version issues reports available [here](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/secure/ConfigureReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10281&version=11322). Saw quite a few things mentioned about tags in v 4.0.2. It is better to streamline the process of compiling your custom code against the latest version sooner than later :)